# DIctionary of Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I m doing stuff in which i need sorting as per category.

I have array of objects having objects as
array1 = name,roll number,group name.
array2 = name,roll number,group name.

I want to categorized above array based on same group. I don t want to compare with hard coded group name.
It means i want members with same country name in separate array. Here array count will not be hardcoded. It will create as data is present. My data is as below.

Please suggest me any logic.

Thanks...

Item 0
Student Name ="ABC"; Roll No ="12"; Country ="USA"

Item 1 
Student Name ="DEF"; Roll No ="12"; Country ="INDIA"

Item 2 
Student Name ="DEF"; Roll No ="12"; Country ="INDIA"

Item 3
Student Name ="DEF"; Roll No ="12"; Country ="USA"

Comment: Don't you mean that you have an array of dictionaries? Please edit your question so that it's clear. I think I have an answer for you, but as your question stands now it's not possible to answer.

Comment: I have edited with sample data

Comment: @iSwap So it is an array of dictionaries, then?

Comment: I want make arrays of students with same group name like USAArray having only students from USA

Comment: "I have array of objects having objects as array1"... But `array1` is not an array, right?. You shouldn't call it array then, it's really confusing.

Answer (score 2):

How about just creating a simple class with properties containing these attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `NSArray` containing other `NSArray`s, filled with `NSString` objects (as your edit suggets), why not writing a simple method ?
Here is an example of method for an object having a property called `myItems` of type `NSArray`

```
// NSArray *myItems, containing your stuff

-(NSArray *)itemsWithCountryName:(NSString *)aCountryName {
    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[myItems count]];
    NSArray *myItemAsAnArray;
    for(myItemAsAnArray in [self myItems]) {
        // your edit suggets 2 as the index for the country name
        // maybe you can provide a defined constant
        if([[myItemAsAnArray objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:aCountryName]) {
            [items addObject:myItemAsAnArray];
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

But maybe you work with dictionaries...

```
-(NSArray *)itemsWithCountryName:(NSString *)aCountryName {
    NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[myItems count]];
    NSDictionary *myItemAsAnDictionary;
    for(myItemAsAnDictionary in [self myItems]) {
        // same again for the key
        if([[myItemAsAnArray objectForKey:@"Country"] isEqualToString:aCountryName]) {
            [items addObject:myItemAsAnArray];
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks all, I done grouping by using sort descriptor. At start i used sort descriptor for country name. Then after separated data into separate arrays having students with same country name.